# Using Local Resource and Relative Link in the same UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, nsbundle

I have a problem with a WebView. I'm loading an Html String into a web view. As base URL I need to use my site URL (because there are some relative link inside the html and I cannot modify it).
The problem is that I also need to use some images and css that are stored inside the Application bundle.
So I'm creating a reference to the local resource using this code (the result string is used as src in html file):

```
NSString *cssUrl = [NSString stringWithString:@"file:"]; 
cssUrl = [cssUrl stringByAppendingString:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
cssUrl = [cssUrl stringByAppendingString:@"/story.css"];
```

Then I've also added:

```
cssUrl = [cssUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@"//"];
cssUrl = [cssUrl stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
```

Any idea how to solve the problem and how to create a reference to a file that can be used inside a web view?
Thanks

Francesco

Answer (score 0):

First, import a directory, e.g. one called `web`, into your project where all the files reside. Make sure you select "*Create Group References For Any Folders*" when Xcode asks you.

Now you can load your initial string like this after putting it into a file inside `web`, say `index.html`:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
   @"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"web"];
if (path) 
   [self.webView loadRequest:
     [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];
```

Now all relative source URLs in your string will work as expected, including `<img>`, `<a>` etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what i'm looking for is something different. I need to create a string with an absolute path to the resource inside the bundle that I can use as src attribute inside an html string. I ended up with something like: "file://var//mobile//Applications//E7F7D425-93C0-8903-G60C-G6YYBT892SA3G//My.app//story.css" but when I use that inside an html string is not working

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"story" ofType:@"css"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath];
NSString *theMagicalURLString = [url absoluteString];
```

Comment: Thanks but that still not works. I create the string as you suggest and insert the string in the html  <link rel="stylesheet" href="file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/032TT991-T167-4484-8F6C-0C2561F2824A/MyApp.app/story.css"/>

Comment: @FrancescoPuntillo Your `story.css` is bundled with your app. So your code should look like this, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="story.css"/>`. Try it, this is how It works for me with no problems.

Comment: @skram the problem is that the base url in the view is not the application bundle so I'm asking if it's possible to have an absolute link to a resource in the bundle. it seems that it's not possible

Comment: @FrancescoPuntillo - Here's another idea for you: Instead of trying to link to the external stylesheet, open and copy the entire stylesheet string and insert it in the <HEAD></HEAD> so it's part of the HTML string. That may not help you with other files but it might be a workaround for the CSS. Good luck!

Comment: @skram yes that's a solution for the CSS but obviously that does not work with images. It's so annoying! seems there is no way to obtain an absolute link to be used in UIWebView

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what I was trying to do it's not possible. To use the bundled resource you have to set the base URL of your web view to the resource path.
Thanks to everyone for your help

Francesco